# Change array's column value based on other array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, numpy, data-preprocessing

I have two arrays. 2st array is subset of 1st array. as show below

```
    arr_1 = [[2,5,25],
             [2,6,28],
             [7,6,75],
             [8,4,39],
             [3,1,86],
             [1,4,45],
             [6,5,89],
             [3,4,99]]

    arr_2 = [[7,6,28],
             [8,4,65],
             [1,4,22],
             [6,5,33]]
```

arr_2's (column 1 (x coordinate) and column 2 (y coordinate))  have all values in arr_1's column1 and column 2) but column 3 (Temperature) of arr_2 has different values for the same x and y in arr_1. I have to replace the value of arr_1 Temperature column value with respect to coordinates (x and y) of arr_2. How can I do it?

Like this

```
    new_arr = [[2,5,25],
               [2,6,28],
               [7,6,28],    //75 of arr_1 changed to 28
               [8,4,65],    //39 of arr_1 changed to 65
               [3,1,86],
               [1,4,22],    //45 of arr_1 changed to 22 
               [6,5,33],    //89 of arr_1 changed to 33
               [3,4,99]]
```

```
    for i in range(len(self.dataset[key])):   
        ind = (np.array(self.pad["mesh_pos"][i])[:, None] == np.array(self.dataset["mesh_pos"][i])).all(-1).any(-1)
       
                
        id = np.array((ind==True).nonzero())[0]
        
        for k in range(len(id)):    
          ar[id[k],0] = self.dataset[key][i][0][k]  

        vr.append(ar)

      self.dataset[key] = np.stack(vr, axis=0)
```

I tried above method but my dataset is very huge and takes a lot of time to run. I am looking for numpy function that can make this faster. Can't share whole code
Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can compare each of the array with only the first 2 elements in each row and replace the rows which was matched:

```
arr_1[(arr_2[:,None,:2] == arr_1[:,:2]).all(-1).any(0)] = arr_2
```